# Print out all combinations of X distinct objects chosen from the Y elements of a list

Tags: ruby, combinations, poker

For instance, 5 cards in a poker hand of 52 cards = 2598960 combinations.
How would I actually display all those combinations though?

The code to find the number is easy:

```
def binomial_coef(total,subset)
  factorial(total) / (factorial(subset) * factorial(total - subset))
end

def factorial(n)
  n.downto(1).inject(:*)
end

# different 5 card poker hand combinations
cards = 52
hand_number = 5

puts binomial_coef(cards, hand_number)
```

Any ideas on a solution to printing out the all the actual combinations?
eg:

> 1,2,3,4,5
>   1,2,3,4,6
>   etc.

Or even help gettings started.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [`Array#combination`](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000759)

```
cards = (1..52).to_a
hand_number = 5
cards.combination(hand_number).to_a

=> [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,6],...]
```

Comment: Use block form to avoid storing the entire thing in memory: `(1..52).to_a.combination(5) {|cards| puts cards.join ','}`

Answer (score 1):

```
(1..52).to_a.combination(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
puts (1..52).to_a.combination(5).to_a.inspect
```